# Google Chrome: Override geolocation via console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-chrome-devtools

So a little background for my question; I am writing a simple driving instructions web application using Google Maps directions API which provides me with a LatLng path along with text instructions.

In order to test this application (without driving around in a car) I need to simulate a geolocation-path. Google Chrome supports overriding geolocation data via the sensors developer settings, which works fine with one coordinate at the time.

So my question is - is it possible to set the browsers navigator.geolocation data via the console (i.e. javascript api) instead manually updating the value in the sensors settings menu?

I know that in this case I could just use another input source than the browser geolocation data and use a static array of LatLng's, or override the browsers navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, but I figured that it would be more sophisticated to override the sensors instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to override the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` with your own custom function. Inside the custom function you can customize the value of latitude & longitude.

```
var customPosition = {};
customPosition.coords = {};
customPosition.coords.latitude = 41.89;
customPosition.coords.longitude = 2.89;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error){
    success(customPosition);

};

function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log("latitude: " + latitude);
    console.log("longitude: " + longitude);
  }
```

Comment: Hi this is good but then if we try to check out current position it is not showing custom position check my code jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a7h1qv5y/) I'll be glad if you will able to help me